# How use function keys in iPad with Apple keyboard?

Tags: ipad, terminal, keyboard

I'm trying to use the Apple Wireless keyboard for coding in a terminal (with nano, vim, etc) using a app to access by SSH them in a remote server, and discover that all the function keys (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>f2</kbd>....) are not working.

I have tried with [Prompt2](https://panic.com/prompt/), but this will happen with any app because the <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> keys by default in the iPad are tied to special functions like control brightens.

Is possible to change this?

If not:

- Exist any terminal app that can remap the keys?
- Or exist a code editor with internal ssh terminal that work for remote coding?

Comment: There is no terminal/nano/vim on an iPad, can you please describe your setup with more details?

Comment: Using a app to acces by SSH the terminal/nano in a remote server.

Comment: You will get better answers if you add the name of the app you are using here. Also please edit the additional information directly into the question, it will then automatically be put into the reopen queue.

Comment: This seems to be a customer service issue.  Any SSH client will have the capability to send Fn key, or even ESC key sequences to your terminal session.  In fact, I was looking at the home page of the product you referenced and one of the pics in the slide show shoes Fn Keys.

Comment: But the functions keys are NOT send. If I hit F1 it not register as F1, instead it change the screen brightens. This is a system level, so not even get into the specific app.

Comment: They are on the screen, meaning they are "soft keys"  are you hitting those?

Comment: " Apple Wireless keyboard ". Is hardware keyboard, not on screen.

Answer (score 1):

**When using the Apple Wireless Keyboard with an iPad device, not all function keys work.** From Apple's Support Article:  [Apple Wireless Keyboard and Magic Keyboard compatibility with iOS devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202041):

[image: iOS Device Keyboard Compatibility]

Since the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys don't work per Apple, it's a safe bet that you won't be able to remap them.  You have to recognize them in order to reassign their function.

This is most likely the reason that you will need to utilize the softkeys provided for by the App.

[image: Function Keys]

What you can try is using the Escape sequence: <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd>  combination where <kbd>#</kbd> is the number of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key you are trying to press (i.e. <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> for <kbd>F2</kbd>)